# Setting up FTP via Windows Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ftp, windows-explorer

I can't see how to do this on windows 7

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/516/Setting+up+FTP+via+Windows+Explorer

Click on Add Network Place.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.redmondpie.com/access-ftp-sites-natively-in-windows-7/) explains it pretty well. Basically just map it as a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps to map the FTP site as a drive on your computer which in turn can be opened with Windows Explorer.

1. Open the **Control Panel** and go to **Internet Options**
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab and under Browsing make sure that **Enable FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)**
3. Scroll down to **Use Passive FTP (for Firewall and DSL modem compatibility.)** and make sure that it's checked.
4. Go to **Computer** and at the top click **Map Network Drive**
5. Type in the address of the FTP site
6. Type in the login credentials
7. You should now be able to access that FTP as a drive within Windows Explorer.